# How do I save List of Checkboxes with value as Id to a database?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have lists of courses from different table displaying on the same view as shown below[image]

I want a user to select the courses he wants to register by selecting the checkboxes.
How do I get the Id's of the courses selected, then pass to the controller to save to another table.

I have my HTML code as this

```html
    @model FlexSchool.Data.Models.ClassModelIndex

                    <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.AdmInstAssignCourses.Where(m => m.IsCompulsory == true))
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="check" value="@item.AdmInstCourses.CourseId" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmInstCourses.CourseCode) </td>
                                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmInstCourses.CourseName)</td>
                                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmInstCourses.Units)</td>

                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
```

Where `ClassModelIndex` is a class of `IEnumerable` Classes which i used in displaying different tables to list.

My button goes thus `<input type="submit" value="Register Courses" id="register" class="btn btn-rose" />`

My script looks like this

```cs
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#register").click(function () {
            var selectedIDs = [];
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({

                url = "/Course/RegisterCourse",
                type = "POST",
                data = JSON.stringify({ courseIDs: selectedIDs }),
                contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType = "json",
                success = function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error = function () {
                    alert("Error while registering courses!");
                },
            });
        });



</script>
```

My `Controller` is

```
    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterCourse(List<string> courseIDs)
        {

            var user = HttpContext.Session.GetString(InstName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

            foreach (string courseID in courseIDs)
            {
                AdmInstCourses obj = await _context.AdmInstCourses.FindAsync(courseID);
                var mycourses = new CourseRegModel { CourseCode = obj.CourseCode, CourseTitle = obj.CourseName, CourseUnit = obj.Units};
                _context.Add(mycourses);

            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("MyCourses", "Course");
        }
```

But when I run the code in debugging mode, I notice my `courseIDs` is not getting any list of string as Id. So it is either the `script` is not getting the checked boxes to pass to the controller.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the JavaScript Code. You have missed `:checked`.Use following code to get all checked values. And make sure no space between `input[type="checkbox"]` and `:checked`.

```
var selectedIDs = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    // looping through each checkbox and storing values in array for checked ones.
    selectedIDs .push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @Brainiac005 are you getting at least one value? (value of the first row)

Comment: Nope am not getting any value.The javascript does not performs the redirect to the action through the Url specified in it. I used `<form action>` method to redirect to my action in the controller when button is clicked.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with Ajax call. Try this

`$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RegisterCourse", "Course")',
                type: "POST",
                data = JSON.stringify({ 'courseIDs' : selectedIDs }),
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType = "json",
                success : function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function () {
                    alert("Error while registering courses!");
                },
            });`

Comment: Thanks, But i have been able to get my ajax call working by using this `var options = {}; options.url = "@Url.Action("RegisterCourse","Course")"; options.type = "POST"; options.data = JSON.stringify({ 'courseIDs': selectedIDs }); options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"; options.dataType = "json", options.success = function () {  alert("Registering Courses");  }; options.error = function () { alert("Error while Registering Courses"); }; $.ajax(options);`The only challenge i have now is making my action in the controller to get the array of strings coming from the json post.

Comment: Do the values add to the array in server side. Did you try adding `alert(selectedIDs)` just after filling the array before calling the Ajax.

`var selectedIDs = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    // looping through each checkbox and storing values in array for checked ones.
    selectedIDs .push($(this).val());
});

alert(selectedIDs);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Ajax code :

```
var selectedIDs = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
        url : '/Course/RegisterCourse',
        type : "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(selectedIDs),
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function () {
            alert("Error while registering courses!");
        }
    });
```

Directly pass json string(`JSON.stringify(selectedIDs)`) to server side , and in the controller method, use `[FromBody]` to get the values :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterCourse([FromBody]List<string> courseIDs)
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you can't put ids in checkbox value, because the value of checkbox can has true or false.

Try to use html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.YourModel[i]) and replace foreach by for.